Truncated distribution and hazard rates in a microeconomic model
I'm trying to prove something related to a labor microeconomic model:
t∈{1,2,3}, A∼N(0,1) (A is fixed across periods),
εt∼N(0,1) (εt are independent for every εt),
c>0 is the cutoff for promotion from easy to hard job (they are only two jobs).
I'm trying to show that for the same cohort, the expected value of workers in the hard job in t=3, is bigger then the expected value of workers in the hard job in t=2. Meaning:
E[A+ε3|(A+ε1>c) ^ (A+ε2>c)] > E[A+ε2|A+ε1>c]
(Intuitively it is quite clear, it is the same group - once with one limitation and a second time with two limitations).
I tried to tackle it with Truncated distribution and hazard rates:
If I'm not wrong, the truncated normal distribution for a variable A+ϵt conditioned on A+ϵt>c, is given by: λ(c)=ϕ(c)/( 1−Φ(c)), which is the hazard rate.
Now, I'm not sure how to approach E[A+ε3|(A+ε1>c) ^ (A+ε2>c)], is it equal to λ(√c), λ(√2c) or even 2λ(c)?
I'm getting lost in trying to prove it one way or another, and thought maybe someone here could help me.
